# agrep not working when have string with spaces, for stringmatching

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy-search, agrep

I have string called 'fish cakes'. I have an eligible dictionary of words, that contains "lemon", and "fish". 
I want agrep to match fish cakes to string fish in the eligible dictionary. But it won't work. It'll match fish with fish cakes.

I want it to detect typos of input data, and I have an eligible dictionary of the eligible words. And i want to suggest what was the appropriate word. So if I had lmon I want to say, did you mean 'lemon'. If i had fish cakes, i want to go, did you mean fish?

```
agrep("fish", c("lemon", "fish cakes"))
```

Will return index 2, matching it with fish cakes

if I do `agrep("fish cakes", c("lemon", "fish"))`

It returns nothing, meaning it doesn't match.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Try with `adist` `which.min(adist("fish cakes", v1))#
[1] 2`

Comment: Sure, I want it to detect typos of input data, and I have an eligible dictionary of the eligible words. And i want to suggest what was the appropriate word. So if I had lmon I want to say, did you mean 'lemon'. If i had fish cakes, i want to go, did you mean fish?

Comment: This works: `max.distance = c(insertions = 6)` but I find it a bit too much :)